# Javascript - Return day in input field from date in another input field

Tags: javascript

Part of the form I'm creating has two fields, a day field and a date field.  The user will input a date in field 1 (Date) and field 2 (Day) will automatically be populated with the day of the week for that date.  I've been trying to piece together the code for the things I need to do (auto-populating a field, returning a day of the week, etc) but it doesn't seem to be working out for me.  I'm using Javascript (read: no JQuery).

Here are is the relevant portion of my HTML:

```
<label>
    <span>input date</span>
    <input type="date" id="date" onChange="getBegDay()">
</label>
<label>
    <span>return day</span>
    <input readonly type="text" id="day">
</label>
```

Here is the relevant portion of my Javascript:

```
function getBegDay() {
    var v = document.getElementById("date").value;
    var n = v.split('-');
    var y = n[0];
    var m = n[1];
    var d = n[2];
    var g = new date(y,m,d);
    var weekday = new array(7);
        var weekday[0] = "Sunday";
        var weekday[1] = "Monday";
        var weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
        var weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
        var weekday[4] = "Thursday";
        var weekday[5] = "Friday";
        var weekday[6] = "Saturday";
    var wd = weekday[g.getDay()];
    document.getElementById('day').value = wd;
```

Comment: What specifically doesn't seem to be working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three mistakes. First `var weekday[0] = "Sunday";`...`var weekday[6] = "Staturday";` you should remove var, like this:

`weekday[0]="Sunday";weekday[1]="Monday";`

Second error:

`new date(y,m,d)` should be `new Date(y,m,d)`.

Third error:

`new array(7)` should be `new Array(7)`.

Comment: OMG THANK YOU!  I knew it had to be something simple like that.  It works perfectly now.

Comment: Okay, I spoke too soon.  one more issue.  I thought I had all the days properly marked in the array, but all the days are returning as two days after the selected day.  For instance today (Tuesday, 9/9/2014) is returning "Thursday", Wednesday, 9/10/2014 is returning "Friday".  I realize I could just change the numbers in the array, but I want to know what's going on for the future.

Comment: @StateofDK var m = n[1]; should been var m = n[1]-1; the moth is between 0 and 11 not 1-12

Answer (score 0):

```
var getDate = function() {
    document.getElementById("day").value = [
      "Sunday", 
      "Monday", 
      "Tuesday", 
      "Wednesday", 
      "Thursday",     
      "Friday", 
      "Saturday"][new Date(Date.parse(event.target.value || event.srcElement.value)).getDay()];
}
```

Comment: Readability, ability to follow the logic & debug it beat brevity any day. This answer would be much better if it used temporary variables.. so engineers can follow & debug it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way, you can use it with all input type date, passing the value by parameters and returning the value to any variable.

```
var valueDate = document.getElementById("txtDate").value;
var dayOfWeek = getDayOfWeek(valueDate);

function getDayOfWeek(valueDateParam) {
    var v = valueDateParam;
    var n = v.split('-');
    var y = n[0];
    var m = n[1];
    var d = n[2];
    var g = new Date(valueDateParam);
    var weekday = new Array(7);
    weekday[0] = "Monday";
    weekday[1] = "Tuesday";
    weekday[2] = "Wednesday";
    weekday[3] = "Thursday";
    weekday[4] = "Friday";
    weekday[5] = "Saturday";
    weekday[6] = "Sunday";
    var wd = weekday[g.getDay()];

    return wd;
}
```